# SFDX conflict with ContentAssets

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a Custom Lightning App, for which I've uploaded an icon in the App Manager interface. I pulled that into SFDX, then deployed with no problem.

Then, I decided to update the logo for branding reasons. So I go into App Manager on the scratch org, clear the old logo, upload the new one. Works fine... until I try to pull it into SFDX, where I get this error:

> ERROR:  Entity of type 'ContentAsset' named 'ProtonTextIcon60x60'
>   cannot be found Entity of type 'ContentAsset' named
>   'ProtonTextIcon60x601' cannot be found.

The first file mentioned is the old icon file. The second file never existed -- don't know why it thinks it's there -- must be a mistake in the metadata?

---

UPDATE: Solved. 
I pushed source to a new scratch org, made the icon change there, pulled it back in to local, then was able to push -f to the original scratch org.

Comment: (It's legit to answer your own question, Pat!)

Comment: @DavidReed, thanks, but my update was really just a workaround. Still don't know why the conflict happened, or more importantly, how to clear it. Those phantom files still show up when I run force:source:status, but I don't know where to find them in the scratch org.

Answer (score 2):

I just went into the same problem.

I emptied the recycle bin but that didn't solve the problem.

I was able to find the references of the now removed content asserts when searching the whole project in the following file
`.sfdx/orgs/{scratch org username}/maxRevision.json`

e.g. search `ProtonTextIcon60x60` or `ProtonTextIcon60x601` in your project if you're op.

Remove those references from the above mentioned file fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found those images in recycle bin. Removing it from recycle bin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me emptying the recycle bin did not help. I uploaded a dummy file several times, one upload for each "missing" file.

Files -> Libraries -> Asset Library

During each upload process enter the exact name of one of the missing files in both fields, name and API name.

After this procedure the sfdx pull in my case went through. I was glad, an evening of GUI changes rescued